# Converting and returning two consts as a single type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, constants

I'm very new to typescript and js.
I have this class:

```
export class Market {
   constructor(public name: string, public code: number) { }
}

export class MarketDetails {
   constructor(
   public market: Market,
   public country: string
   ) {}

   public static convertFromJSON(dbItem: any) {
     const {
       marketName,
       marketId,
       country
     } = dbItem;

     return new MarketDetails(
     // THIS LINE
     marketName + " " + marketId = Market;
     country,
     );
   }
}
```

Basically, in the DB, market is saved as marketName and marketId. I'd like to merge this into one of type Market, but as you can see, am not sure how to do this correctly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just `marketName + " " + marketId` without  `= Market`. Arguments are passed by their position.

Answer (score 0):

Market is not of type string, so marketName + " " + marketId will not work.

Create a new Market in MarketDetails constructor.

```
    return new MarketDetails(
      // THIS LINE
      new Market(marketName, marketId),
      country
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign a value to a type on

```js
marketName + " " + marketId = Market;
```

`Market` is a class type, so you should use `new Market(marketName, marketId)` to create a new instance of this type.

Also, you're using `;` on the constructor arguments, when it should be `,`.

Your final code for `convertFromJSON` will look like this:

```js
public static convertFromJSON(dbItem: any) {
  const {
    marketName,
    marketId,
    country
  } = dbItem;

  return new MarketDetails(
    // THIS LINE
    new Market(marketName, marketId),
    country,
  );
}
```